# How to get values in char array or byte array from DER or PEM files?

Tags: c, file, pem, asn.1, der

I tried to develop some ECC features with PKCS#11 library in C.
I generated some ECC key DER and PEM files by openssl.
For example, below is one of the DER files after decoded by ASN.1 JavaScript decoder.

```
EC_PRIVATEKEY ::= SEQUENCE {
  INTEGER 1
  OCTET STRING 61300E611C121ECBE7C2D49DA8FCD99571DF00296F51C3A9EC02DFF3063DBD3E
  [0]
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7
  [1]
    BIT STRING 0004E924EC46F36A675528E2CA977A7D51C3E510993E092466F1A632419CC4A085F494F1B9D20E4B281484CB971B9AF99F088F11AB17A74928595075877D0047A4CC
}
```

How to get the "OCTET STRING" value in char array or byte array from the file?

The output may looks like :

```
//if the return is char array
privatekey = "61300E611C121ECBE7C2D49DA8FCD99571DF00296F51C3A9EC02DFF3063DBD3E";
```

or

```
//if the return is byte array
privatekey = {0x61,0x30,0x0E,0x61,0x1C,0x12,0x1E,0xCB,0xE7,0xC2,0xD4,0x9D,0xA8,0xFC,0xD9,0x95,0x71,0xDF,0x00,0x29,0x6F,0x51,0xC3,0xA9,0xEC,0x02,0xDF,0xF3,0x06,0x3D,0xBD,0x3E};
```

I have tried some functions from openssl such as PEM_read_ECPrivateKey, but I had not idea about the return data format and struct.

Comment: You just read from the file into a `char[]` buffer?!? What's actually the problem? That's all [well documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

Comment: Hi, πάντα ῥεῖ. I used to input file by ```fopen```. The ```char[]``` is the return I would like to get.

Comment: In c++ we use the `ifstream` class to read from files. If you want to use c you might use `fread()` to read from a file handle you got with `fopen()`. Did you ever program anything in c or c++?!? Also you can't get a `char[]` array of unspecified size. Either you use a fixed size array, and stor the input there repeatedly until you read all data from the file, or you need to maintain a `char*`pointer and a dynamically allocated size along with it.

Comment: Hi, πάντα ῥεῖ. Sorry, I seldom used C/C++ and frequently confused about them. Let me fix the post. It is C rather than C++.